# Spring cloud config automatically refresh all values on the fly

Tags: spring-cloud-config

all:
   In my env, all configurations store in localfile，so my service configuration file stores in classpath:configs/.

So, when files in classpath:configs/ changes, needing refresh on the fly to provide latest properties, I need automatically refresh all values, How could i fulfill this demand?

**`Here is my configuration of config server:`**

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8003
endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  refresh:
    enabled: true
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: classpath:/
 etcd:
   conn:
     etcdPassword: 134
     etcdUrls:
     - http://localhost:2379
     etcdUsername: root
     enabled: true
   etcdServicePrefix: /congiguration/project1/
   enabled: true
   timeout: 1
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configurations
  profiles:
     active: native
```

I have an configurations.yml lays in moudule **resources** dir:

**configurations(-default or not).yml**

```
prop1: Hello
prop2: world
etcd:
   conn:
     etcdPassword: 134
```

**`Here is my configuration of config client:`**

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configurations
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8003/
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 7002
    management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

**Entrypoint**

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
class TestController {
@Value("${prop2}")
private String prop2;
@RequestMapping("/prop2")
public String from() {
    return this.prop2;
  }
}
```

It could print "world" when visit `http://localhost:7002/prop2/` in browser, but when config server **`resources/configurations.yml`** changed, then `curl -X POST http://localhost:7002/refresh` nothing changed and just return [](It should return ["prop2"]) and the same result by visiting `http://localhost:7002/prop2/`.

logs in console when post /refresh:

**Config Server:**

```
017-06-14 19:03:07.301  INFO 69939 --- [nio-8003-exec-4] 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext 
Refreshingorg.springframework.context.annotation.
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@45daa065: startup date [Wed Jun 14 19:03:07 
CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-14 19:03:07.320  INFO 69939 --- [nio-8003-exec-4] 
o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: 
classpath:configs/configurations.yaml
2017-06-14 19:03:07.320  INFO 69939 --- [nio-8003-exec-4] 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
@45daa065: startup date [Wed Jun 14 19:03:07 CST 2017]; root of context 
hierarchy
```

**Config Client:**

```
2017-06-14 19:03:07.064  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: 
http://localhost:8003/
2017-06-14 19:03:07.322  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: 
name=configurations, profiles=[default], label=master, version=null
2017-06-14 19:03:07.322  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: 
CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=
[MapPropertySource [name='classpath:configs/configurations.yaml']]]
2017-06-14 19:03:07.324  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back 
to default profiles: default
2017-06-14 19:03:07.326  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing 
 org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
@2ff4dec0: startup date [Wed Jun 14 19:03:07 CST 2017]; parent: 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@109b
36f8
2017-06-14 19:03:07.336  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.511 
seconds (JVM running for 231.593)
2017-06-14 19:03:07.336  INFO 69942 --- [nio-7002-exec-3] 
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ff
4dec0: startup date [Wed Jun 14 19:03:07 CST 2017]; parent: 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@109b
36f8
```

Comment: To refresh manually we need to do a POST call to http://serveraddress/bus/refresh. You can listen on the refresh event and do a POST to that address.

Comment: @Shubham Agarwal,  hi, i have post my code, I can not figure out what is the problem...
`curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/refresh, return:[]`

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/bus/refresh, return: "status":404,"error":"Not Found"`

so, you mean use this one `https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus` to fulfill my demand?

Comment: I noticed that the `native` profile is not activated in your configuration, are you activating that profile?  The default search location when that profile is active is the classpath so there is no need to specify that.

Comment: @RyanBaxter I just posted the remaining configuration about configurations.yml and bootstrap.yml" I had already actived native profile and use as applications of configurations, is there any problems?
Oh, furthermore, my config server is `localhost:9000`, my config client is `localhost:8000`, i fresh through `curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/refresh`, does this correct ?

Comment: Is the `bootstrap.yml` file for the config server or the config client.  The `native` profile should be enabled on the config server.  I am confused because you have `spring.application.name` set to `configurations in the `bootstrap.yml` file and the then have a configuration file called `configurations.yml`.  I assume `configurations.yml` is the configuration for the config client, no?

Comment: @RyanBaxter `bootstrap.yml` is for config server, so does the native attribute,  you could see that native is enabled by `active: native` , my application name is **configurations**, so I named my file configurations.yml

Comment: @RyanBaxter, I changed the mode to git backend, it workded ,but none with file backend.....

Comment: It should work with the native backend.

Comment: OK.  Having the `spring.application.name` set to `configurations` for both the config client and config server is a bit confusing.  It must be something with the way you are configuring the native profile.  If you can provide a sample client and server that would help.

Comment: @RyanBaxter, hi, I have changed my question detail by adding config server/config client configuration detail, I am very appreciating your effort, many and many thanks for your patient :)

Comment: @RyanBaxter Please see the log  when POST /refresh to client

Comment: @spencergibb, Is there any tutorial for local file backend config and refresh example?The only difference between git and file is the **searchLocations** and   **profiles: active: native**. Both git and file backend mode , the config client could get annotation value provided by config server ,but refresh only work on git backend but not file backend when some changes happen(change value in configurations.yml for both mode and git commit and push for git backend), I am wondering start a bug issue on git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a restriction of loading configuration from the classpath.  Since you cannot change the classpath dynamically while the application is running we cannot reload the changes.  The recommended way (as pointed out in the documentation) is to specify a search path location outside of the application (and also a location that is highly available) for production use cases.  When you specify a search path location you can update the configuration and the config server will pick up those changes.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_file_system_backend

Comment: firstly, thanks for u answer, I have been waiting for that a whole day...
I trace the log of using git backend, it shows:`Adding property source: file:/var/folders/qw/xpctt_js59v0zdk5bh2_x0j00000gn/T/config-repo-3033555073429244269/spring-cloud-etcd-config/src/main/resources/configs/configurations.yaml`, that is outside of the application.
I will try it first!